# tumblr theme not showing images and videos

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

i used the theme maximize from adorablethemes ( https://github.com/adorablethemes/themes/blob/master/legacy/maximize.txt) for quite a while and was very very happy with it.

but now the theme shows nothing more on the main page ... no images no videos etc..

my testblog with exactly the theme https://friedmakerwolf.tumblr.com/

I thought or think that has to do with the NPF of tumblr.

I also asked glenn from https://glenthemes.tumblr.com/ on discord because of his npf fix and he said that probably the whole theme would have to be recoded but he has no time.

now my question here ... is there someone here who can look at it and help me there. i would also give money if necessary.

Yes I know... why not ask the creator of the theme ... I've written to him on github and instagram but no one responds....

and it should only be visible again at the end with the already existing "addons". No desgin changes.

thanks in advance for possible help

I thought or think that has to do with the NPF of tumblr.

I also asked glenn from https://glenthemes.tumblr.com/ on discord because of his npf fix and he said that probably the whole theme would have to be recoded but he has no time.

Comment: Hey! I have taken the theme you linked to and installed it one of my test tumblrs here: https://1001100.tumblr.com/  it seems like it is working OK. It's just that on the index page it depends on what type of post you have, if it's video, text, audio (and possibly one or two others) it can't build anything for the preview/content as this is better suited to photo posts. I have seen this with other themes. I think it would work fine if all your posts were image based. But if you are married to this theme I don't think there is  huge amount you can do. This is fairly standard behaviour